# Porting SQLite statement to Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this select statement working perfectly in SQLite:

```
SELECT extra, count(extra) AS total FROM (SELECT itemID, item, note, sourceItemID, title, collectionName, tagID, modalityID, extra FROM items INNER JOIN factors ON items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID WHERE collectionID = :collectionID AND (tagID = 4 OR tagID = 1) GROUP BY item) GROUP BY extra
```

But when I try to run it at Firebird I receive this error message:

```
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).
```

Please, someone can tell what is happening?
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT extra, count(extra) AS total 
FROM (SELECT extra 
      FROM items 
      INNER JOIN factors ON items.itemID = factors.zotero_itemID 
      WHERE collectionID = :collectionID 
      AND (tagID = 4 OR tagID = 1) 
      ) t
GROUP BY extra
```

If you only need to `count` `extra` from the inner query it is better not to select others and `group by` them, as you aren't using aggregate functions anyway (in the inner query).